# new line data in UITextView

Tags: iphone

i am new in iphone prog...

i am using UITextView to view my data from database...
my app is showing high scores from database.... i stored every row of data in a dictionary and then this dictionary in  an array...

then i did reverse of that here....
here nextclass is object of that class where the actual method of select command is......
and highscore is my textview

NSArray *scores = [nextclass score];

```
NSMutableDictionary *DD;
int a = [scores count];
while(a>0)
{
    DD=[scores objectAtIndex:a-1];

    highscore.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@    --------------------------   %@",[DD objectForKey:@"name"],[DD objectForKey:@"score"]];
    a--;
}
```

the problem is that it replaces the data which was previously added to the textview.....
but i want to show the whole data row by row

waiting for your response......

please help.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
highscore.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@    --------------------------   %@",highscore.text, [DD objectForKey:@"name"],[DD objectForKey:@"score"]];
```

is one option, also you could use the method

> stringByAppendingString

Comment: thanks...
i will try
but know it will work so voted and accepted